# What do the counts in giza++ phrase-table mean?

Tags: machine-translation, moses, giza++

I have been searching for the meaning of numbers in giza++ phrase-table output within the official website (and pdf manual):
http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=FactoredTraining.ScorePhrases

And this is what I've come up to.

Let's say this is a line from phrase-table

```
načiniti na koji ||| way in which ||| 0.833333 * 0.33333 * ||| * ||| 12 3 1
```

that means:

```
e = "načiniti na koji"
f = "way in which"

count(e) = 12
count(f) = 3
count(e, f) = 1

p(f|e) = count(f, e) / count(e) = 1/12 = 0.833333
p(e|f) = count(f, e) / count(f) = 1/3 = 0.333333
```

These all makes perfect sense.

Yet, if I make a text search with textual editor, I get:

```
count("načiniti na koji") = 4
count("way in which") = 9
```

i.e, totally different numbers.

Another strange thing is:

```
osnivanje i ||| the ||| 0.000124085 * 1 * ||| 0-0 ||| 8059 1 1
```

so, considering the explanation from the official website,

```
count("the) = 1,
```

and

```
count("osnivanje i") = 8059.
```

One explanation could be that it might just be opposite.

But, real *count("the") is 21466.*

Are there some other tutorials/manuals that better clarify content of giza++ output files?

Answer (score 3):

So, I figured out it should go something like this:

- Giza runs through the parallel corpus
- whenever two phrases are aligned, they are flushed into textual file, let's name it f_phrases

So may the notation be:

e - foreign giza member

f - english giza member

After this is done, f_phrases is sorted in two ways, and that's how we get two table files

1. **extract.o.sorted**

Pairs are sorted so that all English translations of a certain foreign phrase (e) are next to each other, e.g.

```
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      analysis and
analiza i      and
analiza i      evaluation and
analiza i      the analysis and
analiza i      through evaluation and
```

therefore we conclude that

> count(e) = count("analiza i") = 17

Afterwards, pairs are sorted so that all foreign language translations of a certain native phrase (f) are next to each other, e.g.

2. **extract.inv.sorted**

> ```
> analysis and              Analysis and
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> analysis and              analiza i
> ```

and we see that `count(f) = count("analysis and") = 14`

considering it is the same table, just sorted in other manner, we see that `count("analysis and", "analiza i") = count("analiza i", "analysis and") = 17`

Resulting phrase-table then looks like:

```
analiza i|||analysis and|||     14      |||             17|||               13

e       ||| f        ||| count(f) ||| count(e)   ||| count(e, f) = count(f, e)
```

When conditional probabilities are calculated, then the inverse order is used, as the order is in the phrase-table:

```
p(e|f) = p(e, f) / p(f) phrase translation probability 
p(f|e) = p(f, e) / p(e) inverse phrase translation probability
```